# Can't get border-spacing to work

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I was designing a very simple page for a friend. I want to make it responsive-ish, and used a table. I can't get border-spacing to work tho...

You can see my work here: https://jsfiddle.net/Lt2wpehL/

Maybe this part overrides something?

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {    
.info td {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
.info tr,
.info td:nth-child(3) {
    float: none;      
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Don't use tables for page layout, There are much better, flexible and responsive methods.

Comment: I know, but I know tables and I figured it was an easy option

Comment: Once you set `border-collapse: collapse`, the `border-spacing` property will have no effect.  Using table mark-up will probably get in the way of getting the layout that you want.  For large screens, you want 3 items in a row, and for small screens, 3 items in a column.

Comment: Even if you know about how tables works... as layouts they are absolutely (And I'm so happy about it) obsolet. Give your friend a favour and use actual layout techniques... you don't even have to learn much, many css layouts already around for you to download, to include in your projects and use just adding some classes to your containers.

Answer (score 0):

It's already been mentioned, but generally speaking, tables are pretty big faux pas these days. However, don't be afraid of using other methods! There are some very, very simple grid patterns available to you.

Consider using:

**Bootstrap** (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

Or the ever present **960 Grid System** (http://960.gs/)

These systems are pre-written, and I think you'll find they server you better and save you a lot of time with future projects.